# How to remove duplicate words from a plain text file using unix commands on windows

Tags: file, duplicates, plaintext

I have a plain text file with words, which are separated by comma, for example:

```
word1, word2, word3, word2, word4, word5, word 3, word6, word7, word3
```

i want to delete the duplicates and to become:

```
word1, word2, word3, word4, word5, word6, word7
```

[There is a realy good article for Linux already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952268/648597) So i installed gnuwin .... an gave up after a 1 h ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the words on different lines in your file, say, f1.txt. You may refer to [How to replace a character by a newline in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71323/how-to-replace-a-character-for-a-newline-in-vim) for this.
2. Then execute command "sort -u f1.text > f2.txt"
3. Combine the words of f2.txt into a line or lines if required.