# How can I find repeated words in a file using grep/egrep?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep, word-boundary

I need to find repeated words in a file using egrep (or grep -e) in unix (bash)

I tried:

```
egrep "(\<[a-zA-Z]+\>) \1" file.txt
```

and

```
egrep "(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b) \1" file.txt
```

but for some reason these consider things to be repeats that aren't!
for example, it thinks the string "word words" meets the criteria despite the word boundary condition `\>`  or `\b`.

Comment: For a better understanding, show some sample input, desired output, etc. The only thing we can say now is "yes, it works as intended".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\1` matches whatever string was matched by the first capture. That is not the same as matching the same pattern as was matched by the first capture. So the fact that the first capture matched on a word boundary is no longer relevant, even though the `\b` is inside the capture parentheses.

If you want the second instance to also be on a word boundary, you need to say so:

```
egrep "(\b[a-zA-Z]+) \1\b" file.txt
```

That is no different from:

```
egrep "\b([a-zA-Z]+) \1\b" file.txt
```

The space in the pattern forces a word boundary, so I removed the redundant `\b`s. If you wanted to be more explicit, you could put them in:

```
egrep "\<([a-zA-Z]+)\> \<\1\>" file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

I use

```
pcregrep -M '(\b[a-zA-Z]+)\s+\1\b' *
```

to check my documents for such errors. This also works if there is a line break between the duplicated words.

Explanation:

- `-M, --multiline` run in multiline mode (important if a line break is between the duplicated words.
- `[a-zA-Z]+`: Match words
- `\b`: Word boundary, see [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(\b[a-zA-Z]+)` group it
- `\s+` match at least one (but as many more as necessary) whitespace characters. This includes newline.
- `\1`: Match whatever was in the first group

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. See what `man grep` says:

> **The Backslash Character and Special Expressions**
>
> The symbols \< and > respectively match the empty string at the
>   beginning and end of a word. The symbol \b matches the empty string at
>   the edge of a word, and \B matches the empty string provided it's not
>   at the edge of a word. The symbol \w is a synonym for [*[:alnum:]] and
>   \W is a synonym for [^*[:alnum:]].

and then in another place we see what "word" is:

> **Matching Control**
>
> Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.

So this is what will produce:

```
$ cat a
hello bye
hello and and bye
words words
this are words words
"words words"
$ egrep "(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b) \1" a
hello and and bye
words words
this are words words
"words words"
$ egrep "(\<[a-zA-Z]+\>) \1" a
hello and and bye
words words
this are words words
"words words"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
egrep "(\<[a-zA-Z]+>) \<\1\>" file.txt
```

fixes the problem.

basically, you have to tell \1 that it needs to stay in word boundaries too

Comment: Doesn't work, since `\>` and `>` are different. (And how does it differ from the accepted answer, other than the typo?) Also, please learn how to format code, so that `<` and `>` aren't intepreted as HTML. See