# removing duplicate words from sentences in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

how can I remove the duplicate words from sentences in file ,each sentence written in a separate line.

thank you

I have these sentences in file

```
hello every body hello
word I should remove the word
how can can i remove it ?
```

the expected out put should be

```
hello every body
word I should remove the
how can i remove it ?
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952268/how-to-remove-duplicate-words-from-a-plain-text-file-using-linux-command might help

Comment: consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update your question accordingly; in particular, provide your sample input, the code you've written, the (wrong) output generated by your script and the (correct) desired output

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the expected output that you want to get from the example input.

Comment: @dwag 
it's the same , but it didn't work ..

Comment: @dawg, it won't help him - while it will strip the dupes it will cull the sentence structures ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(++arr[$i]==1) print $i}' file
```

Prints:

```
hello
every
body
word
I
should
remove
the
how
can
i
it
?
```

To maintain the line structure:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
       if(++arr[$i]==1) 
          printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
       print ""}' file
```

Prints:

```
hello every body 
word I should remove the 
how can i it ?
```

If the deduplication is only on a per line basis:

```
awk '{delete arr
      for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
         if(++arr[$i]==1) printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
      print ""}' file
```

Prints:

```
hello every body 
word I should remove the 
how can i remove it ?
```

Comment: Much better like that ;)